# Puppeteer node.js: Access denied when downloading image

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, fs, createwritestream

I'm trying to download an image using the fs.createWriteStream function. I'm able to download the image but it's damaged/corrupted.I'm getting an error message saying:
"Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "https:..." on this server"

I'm using puppeteer on headless:false mode and I also set the user agent to:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")

The function I'm calling to download the file is the following:

```
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const fs = require ("fs");
const path = require("path");
const URL = require("url").URL;

function download (url, filepath,callback,){

    const userURL = new URL (url);
    const requestCaller = userURL.protocol === "http:" ? http : https;

    const filename = path.basename(url);
  
    const req = requestCaller.get(url, function(res){

         const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(filepath,filename));
         res.pipe(fileStream);

            fileStream.on("error", function(err){
                console.log("Error writing to the stream.");
                console.log(err);
              });
            fileStream.on("close",function(){
                callback(filename);

            });

            fileStream.on("finish", function(){
                fileStream.close()
            });
        });
         req.on("error", function(err){
             console.log("Error downloading the file.");
             console.log(err);  
         });
         
     };

   module.exports.download = download;
```

The URL of the image I'm trying to download is this:

https://www.vrisko.gr/logos/775165.jpg

It seems I'm getting blocked by the server but I don't know what else to do apart from setting the user agent and not running puppeteer in headless mode. Any thoughts?

[EDIT]

Apparently there is an issue with the CORS policy. I checked the Network call and I see the following:

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
sec-fetch-site: none

Whereas when I simply manually navigate from my browser, I get this:

Referrer Policy: unsafe-url
sec-fetch-site: same-origin

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you mixed 2 things there: `puppeteer` and `http request`. What the above code does is send a GET request to the `url` passed and writes the response to a file. If you wish to scrape the page using `puppeteer`, you should `goto` the URL and take a `screenshot` instead.

Comment: I don't want to get a screenshot. I want to download the image. If I take a screenshot it will capture the whole page which has a black background. I'm using the https module to request the link of the image that I'm getting from the previous link here:

Comment: https://www.vrisko.gr/advdetails/5d_4b31e2e7g2h__bgbiaa30cd_7_2_ibf45bi04623g6g10d2a06c440d_d6a7i?what=%CE%9A%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BB%CF%89%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%BC%CF%8C%CF%82%20%CE%A0%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%AF%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7%20%CE%9A%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AF%CE%B4%CE%B9%CF%89%CE%BD%20%CE%96%CF%8E%CF%89%CE%BD&where=%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1%20%CE%91%CE%A4%CE%A4%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%97%CE%A3&region=1

Comment: Apparently there is an issue with the CORS policy. I checked the Network call and I see the following:
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
....
sec-fetch-site: none
Whereas when I simply manually navigate from my browser, I get this:
Referrer Policy: unsafe-url
....
sec-fetch-site: same-origin

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all my errors with CORS policy by using npm module cors. Install it with 'npm install cors' and do this:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```